# Edit to remove "Tags" from Question Title

Tags: discussion, edits

I submitted a question and following the guides in "Asking Help" I included this descriptive title:

> Auth0 - Passwordless SMS - Payload Validation Error on
>   Passwordless/Verify

A user then edited the title to remove "Auth0 - Passwordless SMS" with the comment "Do not put tags in titles".

The Asking Help guide specifically states:

> The title is the first thing potential answerers will see, and if your
>   title isn't interesting, they won't read the rest. So make it count:
>
> Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague and have to sum up your
>   entire question in one sentence: what details can you include that
>   will help someone identify and solve your problem? Include any error
>   messages, **key APIs**, or unusual circumstances that make your question
>   different from similar questions already on the site.

I compromised and simply edited the title to include "Auth0" to provide some context to the error I was receiving.

The user then edited the question again to remove "Auth0" and left the same comment.

Obviously "Do not put tags in titles" is a non-existant rule as that would mean titles would never contain languages, APIs, frameworks, etc.

Is there some reason this user is so adamant about removing the context of my question from the title that I'm unaware of?

[Payload Validation Error on Passwordless/Verify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47637102/payload-validation-error-on-passwordless-verify)

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47637102/revisions

Comment: Title of this post should be "[Edits] [tags] [title] - remove from?" :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I wouldn't say "Do not put tags in titles" is a rule so much as it is a [guideline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles/130208#130208). But it definitely exists. For a good reason.

What it means is not putting keywords in titles in such a way that it makes it look like you're trying to use the title field for tags, when the tags field exists for that very purpose. That's what you're doing, and it makes for a very unreadable title.

If you can write a good title that makes use of those keywords, of course we want you to use that title, because it contains those keywords. But what you have is a series of keywords followed by an okay title.

Comment: So a better title would be something like "Payload Validation Error on Auth0's Passwordless/Verify endpoint"?

Comment: @Jeff Swensen: Only marginally, but it certainly beats "Auth0 - Passwordless SMS - Payload Validation Error on Passwordless/Verify". Writing a good title is hard, and some types of questions simply don't lend themselves to nice-sounding titles, so I don't blame you.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. Need some practice on titles

Comment: How does this (adding or not adding tags in title) affect the SO search and SO search through google?

Comment: @Amit Joshi: The site handles SEO for you so you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 6):

Key APIs are fine if you can work them in organically - but don't go overboard. Remember, your goal is to attract folks who've encountered the same / similar problems to read and answer your question: to that end, focus first on including the details that specifically identify your question.

I'd argue the most specific detail for your question is *the actual error* that's being returned. Which neither you nor the editor saw fit to include...

I've edited the title to add in that key detail, as well as working Auth0 into it in a more organic fashion.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Makes more sense now